# Regular expressions - Form data validation in JS

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate postal-code input with so-called regular expressions. Below is my code which doesn't seem to work for some reason. I need a solution completely in pure JS, not in other frameworks.

```js
function postalCodeValidate() {
  var postalCode = document.getElementbyID("postalcode").value;
  var errorMessage = document.getElementbyID("pcodeerror").innerHTML;
  var postalPattern = /^\d{2}-\d{3}$/;
  
  if (POSTALCODE == "") {
    errorMessage = "You must enter a postal code!";
  } else if (POSTALCODE.match(postalPattern) == null) {
    errorMessage = "Wrong postal code format (00-000)";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frm">
  <form>
    <h5>Enter adress details</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code (00-000)">
      <div id="pcodeerror"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postalCodeValidate();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <a href="#Register">
      <h6>Register</h6>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/altug09/pen/yREoLe

Comment: `errorMessage = "..."` won't change the content of the element with id `pcodeerror`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have some problems:**

`POSTALCODE` doesn't exist, JS is case-sensitive, so POSTALCODE !== postalCode.

Assiging the string from `document.getElementById("pcodeerror").innerHTML` to a variable and then assign a message to that variable is not going to update `document.getElementById("pcodeerror").innerHTML`.  So, you need to understand how the reference works, Etc.

And finally, you don't need the function `match` because you're not using the returned array.  So, use the function `test` to check the regexp over a specific string.

```js
function postalCodeValidate() {
  var postalCode = document.getElementById("postalcode").value;


  var postalPattern = /^\d{2}-\d{3}$/;
  if (postalCode == "") {
    document.getElementById("pcodeerror").innerHTML = "You must enter a postal code!";
  } else if (!postalPattern.test(postalCode)) {
    document.getElementById("pcodeerror").innerHTML = "Wrong postal code format (00-000)";

  }

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #283c86;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #45a247, #283c86);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #45a247, #283c86);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.frm {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #ebebe0;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn {
  float: right;
}

#mailerror,
#passerror {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="frm">
  <form>
    <h5>Enter adress details</h5>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code (00-000)">
      <div id="pcodeerror"></div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="postalCodeValidate();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <a href="#Register">
      <h6>Register</h6>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ele! I just missed that point, cuz I tried some code with global variables.. That's why I forgot it there in uppercase :)